# Refactoring method according Single Responsibility Principle

Tags: java, refactoring, single-responsibility-principle

I need to test contract obligations program.
I don't see any straightforward way to test this method as written. It's violating the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), and simply doing too many things.
I would ro know, how safely extract the following responsibilities in to new methods or classes:

```
public void askUserPathAndWord() {

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String path;
        String whatFind;
        BlockingQueue<File> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<File>();

        try {
            System.out.println("Please, enter a Path and Word"
                    + "(which you want to find):");
            System.out.println("Please enter a Path:");
            path = bufferedReader.readLine();
            System.out.println("Please enter a Word:");
            whatFind = bufferedReader.readLine();

            if (path != null && whatFind != null) {

                File endOfWorkFile = new File("GameOver.tmp");
                CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(2);

                FolderScan folderScan = new FolderScan(path, queue, latch,
                        endOfWorkFile);
                FileScan fileScan = new FileScan(whatFind, queue, latch,
                        endOfWorkFile);

                Executor executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
                executor.execute(folderScan);
                executor.execute(fileScan);

                latch.await();
                System.out.println("Thank you!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("You did not enter anything");
            }

        } catch (IOException | RuntimeException e) {
            System.out.println("Wrong input!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Interrupted.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**Qustions:**
How we able to do safely next steps:

- Ask the user for word and path;
- Given a word, create a FileScan
  with the correct parameters (a Factory);
- Given a path, create a
  FolderScan with the correct parameters (a Factory);
- Given two
  runnables and a latch, create a ExecutorService, queue them, and wait
  on the latch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would refactorize that method, using mainly IDE's extract method feature and common sense. It would be best to write a test for that method also to be sure that refactorization didn't broke anything.

```
class PathAndWord {
    final String path;
    final String whatFind;

    PathAndWord(String path, String whatFind) {
        this.path = path;
        this.whatFind = whatFind;
    }

    boolean isProperlyInitialized() {
        return path != null && whatFind != null;
    }
}

public void askUserPathAndWord() {
    try {
        tryToAskUserPathAndWord();
    } catch (IOException | RuntimeException e) {
        System.out.println("Wrong input!");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println("Interrupted.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void tryToAskUserPathAndWord() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    PathAndWord pathAndWord = readPathAndWord();

    if (pathAndWord.isProperlyInitialized()) {
        performScan(pathAndWord, "GameOver.tmp");
        System.out.println("Thank you!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("You did not enter anything");
    }
}

private PathAndWord readPathAndWord() throws IOException {
    System.out.println("Please, enter a Path and Word (which you want to find):");

    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    String path = readPath(bufferedReader);
    String whatFind = readWord(bufferedReader);
    return new PathAndWord(path, whatFind);
}

private String readPath(BufferedReader bufferedReader) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("Please enter a Path:");
    return bufferedReader.readLine();
}

private String readWord(BufferedReader bufferedReader) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("Please enter a Word:");
    return bufferedReader.readLine();
}

private void performScan(PathAndWord pathAndWord, String endOfWorkFileName) throws InterruptedException {
    BlockingQueue<File> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<File>();

    File endOfWorkFile = new File(endOfWorkFileName);
    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(2);

    FolderScan folderScan = new FolderScan(pathAndWord.path, queue, latch,
            endOfWorkFile);
    FileScan fileScan = new FileScan(pathAndWord.whatFind, queue, latch,
            endOfWorkFile);

    Executor executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    executor.execute(folderScan);
    executor.execute(fileScan);

    latch.await();
}
```

Comment: How able to checking user's path input genal correctly by `resolve(Path ..)`, now ? And will be prove that program don't "fall down".

Comment: To be "sure" that the refactorization is correct you should have automatic tests (or perform manual test) that cover 100% of method funcionality. In real world you will test some functionalities (most common, and some edge cases). That would give you enought certainty to assume that refactorization was correct. But nevertheless you have to test it.

Comment: I meant that need to check user input path. If this path isn't file path, but folder path. If you input file path program "fall down". I understand that this is a bug but generally I don't know how to check this?

Comment: OK, so you can create a new File object with given path, and then use methods exists() and isFile() or isDirectory(). I think this should be sufficient. Or if that solution doesn't work for you, you can try to parse the path String.

Answer (score 3):

As with most refactorings a safe first step is to test the method as it currently stands.
Then refactor the code into logical groups that have the necessary responsibilities - throughout this process your previously written tests should not break.
Then you can abandon your original test which tests too many things in favour of tests that solely make assertions about the new code that you have written

Comment: Can we divade method according [Single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) before stert testing? Make code readable simpler.

Comment: That might be possible, but it would work only for simple cases. In more complex code, if your refactorization would broke something it might be hard to find what is the problem. On the other hand if you will have test before refactorization you will be able to refactorize it step by step and therefore possible errors will be easy to spot.